# Thymeleaf exception unhandled

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, thymeleaf

I'm trying to handle thyemeaf exceptions that are thrown from .html files using thymeleaf and Spring Boot, but I don't find the way to catch any of them.

An example of an error (that I know how to fix in thymeleaf) is the following one.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [div_error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "folder/file" - line XX, col XX)
```

> I know how to solve this error, but I want to catch it while execution of program

This exception (org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException), as you can see, comes from thymeleaf but the typical Exception handler does not catch it.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleMethodException(final HttpServletRequest request, Exception exception, HttpSession session, Model model) {

        // more code here

        return "custom_error/internal_error";
    }
}
```

But as I said, exceptions from "org.thymeleaf.exceptions" does not reach into *handleMethodException*

**UPDATE**

It may be possible that as the exception is thrown on another route

```
src/main/resources/templates/folder/file.html
```

@ExceptionHandler does not recognise it because it is located in another path?

```
src/main/java/[...]/controller/ExceptionController.java
```

> In case that is true, isn't there another option to handle those exceptions then?

I'm trying to learn more about thymeleaf and its functions and I'm curious if there is any way.

Comment: Do any other exceptions end up in the handleMethodException() though? I kind of get the idea that this is not really anything to do with Thymeleaf exceptions specifically, there may be a more global problem with the exception handler setup which would require more code to be shown to figure out what may be wrong. Push comes to shove, these exceptions are just any other RuntimeException.

Comment: Yes! I handle some exceptions like HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 

(405 Http Error) - (Method X not supported)

When I set specific exceptions like the above-mentioned it reaches into method, but some of thymeleaf exceptions like TemplateInputException don't, that's my confusion

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't enough here to really be able to say what might be wrong. If the exceptions are not going to the handler but other exceptions are... then the exception flow must not be what you expect. You'd need a more complete MCVE which demonstrates the exception happening and the exception handler not picking it up. Whatever it is, it is something silly and easy to overlook.

Comment: After all, I am controlling Exception, so I should catch all the exceptions that are thrown during the execution of the program. That's why when a Method Not Supported exception is thrown, I get to that controller.

Comment: The problem I think lies in the location of the file where the exception is thrown, not being encompassed by src/main/java (html templates are located in src/main/resources).

Comment: Is it possible to change the location of these files (and locate them in "java" to see if the exceptions are caught there) or should this path be mandatory?